# Error call php in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

When I write:

```
alert(<?php echo "33333";?>);
```

it works.

If I echo a number, it works too. But if I write

```
alert(<?php echo "346346gj";?>);
```

it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert(<?php echo "33333";?>);` will output `alert(33333);`. And it's a correct javascript syntax.

`alert(<?php echo "346346gj";?>);` will output `alert(346346gj);`. It's not a correct syntax.

When you want to `alert` a string in javascript you write `alert("346346gj");` or `alert('346346gj');`

So you must replace `alert(<?php echo "346346gj";?>);` with one of the following:

- `alert('<?php echo "346346gj";?>');`
- `alert("<?php echo "346346gj";?>");`
- `alert('<?php echo '346346gj';?>');`
- `alert("<?php echo '346346gj';?>");`
- `alert(<?php echo "'346346gj'";?>');`
- `alert(<?php echo '"346346gj"';?>');`

And there are still different conbinations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enclose the generated JS in quotes:

```
alert('<?= $stringVariable ?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but

```
alert(""+number);
```

Maybe I misunderstood you. If you want to print php values in JavaScript, you should request them via ajax. "Hardcoding" them isn't the way to go.

Comment: If he has already the value in php before generating the Javascript, why should he use Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Because in javascript, strings need to be in quotes.. so try

```
alert('<?php echo "33333j";?>');
```

Answer (score 0):

To output any kind of PHP value (except resources) directly into JavaScript, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode).

```
alert(<?php echo json_encode($myvar); ?>);
```

`$myvar` can be pretty much anything, and it will always work. I alwyas use `json_encode` to put a PHP variable into JS.

Comment: Bach Fuc said `why?` not `how?`